# React: Input Field Seems to Be Returning Itself

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm still learning React, and am following a code-along. I have a form that uses semantic ui react components, after struggling with this problem for a day or so, I just copy and pasted from their GitHub, and am still having the same problem:

```
  onSearchChange = (e, data) => {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    this.setState({
      query: data
    });
    this.timer = setTimeout(this.fetchOptions, 1000);
  };

  onChange = (e, data) => {
    this.setState({ query: data.value });
    this.props.onBookSelect(this.state.books[data.value]);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Form>
        <Dropdown
          search
          fluid
          placeholder="Search for a book by title"
          value={this.state.query}
          onSearchChange={this.onSearchChange}
          options={this.state.options}
          loading={this.state.loading}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

The console is throwing me a: Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` supplied to `Dropdown`. It turned out that my value is being passed as an Object that contains my Dropdown component.

As I was writing this question, I realized that I'm in v16 and they were in 15. So, the answer might be as simple as updating the syntax for v16, but I'm not sure how to do that.

**Edit**:
I installed React 15.x, and that did fix the problem I was having, so I guess my real question now is why doesn't `onSearchChange` fire `fetchOptions` when I change `data` to `data.value`. `fetchOptions` is just an axios call that looks like:

```
fetchOptions = () => {
if (!this.state.query) return;
this.setState({ loading: true });
axios
  .get(`/api/books/search?q=${this.state.query}`)
  .then(res => res.data.books)
  .then(books => {
    const options = [];
    const booksHash = {};
    books.forEach(book => {
      booksHash[book.goodreadsId] = book;
      options.push({
        key: book.goodreadsId,
        value: book.goodreadsId,
        text: book.title
      });
    });
    this.setState({ loading: false, options, books: booksHash });
  });
};
```

Comment: What dropdown component are you using, and what is the initial value of query in your component?

Comment: Dropdown is imported from semantic-ui-react, the value attribute wants a String, number or array values. Query is initially set to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the exact same tutorial (Rem Zolotykh's Build Real Web App with React series) and ran into the same problem with the newer version of React.

Found the issue and how to fix it:

Change the onSearchChange function to use data.searchQuery instead of data or data.value:

```
onSearchChange = (e, data) => {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    this.setState({
       query: data.searchQuery // <-- Right here
    });
    this.timer = setTimeout(this.fetchOptions, 1000);
 };
```

That makes it work. (Somewhat unexpectedly, leave it as data.value in the onChange function)

Answer (score -1):

Should be an easy fix, all you need to do is update `onSearchChange`:

```
onSearchChange = (e, data) => {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    this.setState({
      query: data.value
    });
    this.timer = setTimeout(this.fetchOptions, 1000);
};
```

You were saving the argument `data` to `this.state.query`. You actually need to store `data.value` to get the string value. Take a look at how `onSearchChange` works.

```
onSearchChange(event: SyntheticEvent, data: object)
  event: React's original SyntheticEvent.
  data: All props, includes current value of searchQuery.
```

Comment: That was my first instinct, but when I set query to data.value, setState never fires, and query remains an empty string.

Comment: What do you get if you add `console.log(data)` to that function?

Comment: logging data prints an object that seems to contain the Dropdown, logging data.value prints an empty string.